# Buttons Android Disabled looks Active

Tags: android, button

I'm an Android beginner and I am currently trying to make my first calculator app.

My biggest inspiration is the Windows 10 built-in calc. I want some buttons to be disabled during some actions to get rid of bugs but I don't like the look of disabled-buttons.

I'd rather have them enabled but make them so they don't perform any action. I tried to use `.setClickable(false)` but then there is no sound of click as well as no animation of clicking (shadow).

Can they be fully clickable but have no action?

Comment: you can use variable for that because you dont want to disable to button so just use if(condition) inside of the button click event

Comment: looks like we had the same idea, @AhmetAcikalin ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a variable to decide that. Put it somewhere in your class:

```
private boolean clicked = false;
```

Then(at the on click listener of the button):

```
if (clicked) {
  //your action happens here(it wouldn't happen, until you change clicked to true)
}
```

Comment: Smart. Could've thought about it. Thank you :)

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
btn.setEnabled(false);
```

What it does is disable the button and make it not clickable.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@color/disabled_color" android:state_enabled="false" />
    <item android:drawable="@color/enabled_color" android:state_enabled="true"/>
</selector>
```

You can use the above xml (let's say we name it button_selector.xml) 
Apply it as background for your Button (in your activity layout) 
In your code, based on your actions, use

```
setEnabled(false);
```

and that's it. You can change it back programmatically when you want the button to be active again. Also, you can add

```
setFocusable(false);
setFocusableInTouchMode(false);
setClickable(false);
```